# How to place point-count information on the line of a displayed equation in exam document class

Tags: equations, exam

I was preparing a question paper in `exam` document class where I am dropping the points at right. Now if I have a `displaystyle` equation line as the last line of my question, then the points are getting dropped in the next line. How do I make it fall in the same line?

Here is an example:

```
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart[6]
        If $ a,b $ are positive rational numbers then prove that 
\[ a^ab^b\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{a+b}\ge a^bb^a. \] \droppoints
\end{subparts}
```

This yields

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\droppoints` is only supposed to be used at the end of a paragraph, a logical solution would be to place the display equation inside a `\parbox`.

The second version was discovered by accident.  I really don't understand why it works.

Just for fun, I also show how to put the points inside the margins, which is what I was originally trying to accomplish.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints % optional
\begin{questions} 
\question 
\begin{parts} 
\part 
\begin{subparts}
\subpart[5]
Normal question.\droppoints

\subpart[6]
If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers, prove that
\par\vskip\abovedisplayskip
\parbox{\linewidth}{\[
a^ab^b\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!a+b}\ge a^bb^a\,.
\]}\droppoints% equation in \parbox

\subpart[6]
If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers, prove that
\begin{equation}
a^ab^b\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!a+b}\ge a^bb^a\,.
\tag*{\parbox{1pt}{\droppoints}}% accident
\end{equation}

\subpart[6]
If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers, prove that
\begin{equation}
a^ab^b\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!a+b}\ge a^bb^a\,.
\tag*{[\themarginpoints]}% inside margins
\end{equation}

\end{subparts}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

You could place the `\droppoints` instruction inside an `\mbox` wrapper *before* rather than after `\]`.

[image]

I can't help but make an additional comment: Don't write `If $ a,b $ are positive rational numbers`. While this expression may appear to be "cool" because it's terse, it's mostly just bad style. There's everything to be gained from writing `If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers`. If nothing else, your students will appreciate not being bombarded with needlessly affectated jargon.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints % optional
\begin{questions} 
\question 
\begin{parts} 
\part 
\begin{subparts}
\subpart[6]
If $a$ and $b$ are positive rational numbers, prove that 
\[ 
a^ab^b\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!a+b}\ge a^bb^a\,.  
\mbox{\droppoints}
\]
\end{subparts}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But then it is not getting dropped at the margin.

Comment: Also thanks for your additional comment. Will surely keep that in mind. I have another question regarding your solution. In the expression `\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!a+b}`, what is `\!` doing in `{\!a+b}`. I am quite a new person in `LaTex` environment, so please don't mind if I am being silly!

Comment: @SubhajitPaul - The `\!` particle is "negative thinspace". It serves to place the exponent, `a+b`, closer to the closing parentheses.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul - The `[6]` particle *is* placed at the right-hand margin. It's just that the `\pointsdroppedatright` directive resets the location of the right-hand margin, as is explained in the manual of the `exam` document class.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean one cannot place the point in the same line and with the usual right hand margin?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul - I suggest you consult the manual of the `exam` class for information on your follow-up question.